# after transferring information from time capsule to new MacBook Pro iTunes/AppStore stop working

Tags: mac-appstore, ios-appstore, migration

I choose to use a time capsule to initialize my new MacBook Pro. All went well until I tried to use applications bought from the AppStore. Some of them don't start and eventually ask me for my Apple ID. After some time it gives this:

[image: Sign in to use this application dialog]

The AppStore gives the same connection failed and the iTunes gives me "The network connection timed out"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that was a problem with the AppStore and iTunes connection but it is working now.

Some applications worked when the connection work, but two didn't work until I deleted the application and let the AppStore to install them again